# connection reset by peer Error with nginx Ingress in Kind cluster

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, kind

I installed vault helm chart 0.8.0 in dev mode and nginx ingress controller on Kind cluster and applied the following Ingress resource:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: vault-ingress
  annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
rules:
- host: vault.com
  http:
    paths:
    - path: /v1/*
      backend:
      serviceName: vault
      servicePort: 8200
```

This is the patch for Kind cluster as noted in https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/ingress/:

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
nodes:
- role: control-plane
  kubeadmConfigPatches:
  - |
   kind: InitConfiguration
   nodeRegistration:
     kubeletExtraArgs:
    node-labels: "ingress-ready=true"
  extraPortMappings:
  - containerPort: 8200 # Vault port in K8s
   hostPort: 80 # Vault port on host
- containerPort: 8200 # Vault port in K8s
   hostPort: 443 # Vault port on host
```

when doing the following curl command I get error:

VAULT_ADDR="http://localhost"

vault login  root

Error authenticating: error looking up token: Get "http://localhost/v1/auth/token/lookup-self": read    tcp 127.0.0.1:34596->127.0.0.1:80: read: connection reset by peer

```
Name:             vault-ingress
Namespace:        vault
Address:          localhost
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
Host        Path  Backends
----        ----  --------
vault.com
             /v1/*   vault:8200 (10.244.1.7:8200)
Annotations:  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
Events:
Type    Reason  Age                   From                      Message
 ----    ------  ----                  ----                      -------
Normal  Sync    2m47s (x15 over 10h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

Comment: Try `VAULT_ADDR="http://localhost:8200"`. It looks like the kind container is listening on port 8200, not on 80. Does it work now?

Comment: no tnx it does not work

Comment: In ingress you have `host: vault.com` and the cli is using `localhost` as a domain so ingress wont be able to route it to the right application. Add vault.com domain to `/etc/hosts` file and poinit to 127.0.0.1 and then use `VAULT_ADDR="http://valult.com:8200"` or just delete the host field in ingress obejct.

Comment: That did not work also.. tnx